# SQL QUERY WITH HAVING, count with at least 100 countries

Tags: sql, group-by, compiler-errors, having, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is the task:

How many countries (COUNTRY) have at least 100 series (TYPE = 'TV Show') on Netflix? As a result, only the countries that match the entry are displayed (use HAVING).

My code:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(COUNTRY,',',1), COUNT (*)
FROM NETFLIX_TITLES
GROUP BY SPLIT_PART(COUNTRY,',',1)
HAVING TYPE = 'TV Show' AND COUNT(TYPE) >= 100
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

It gives my this error: SQL compilation error: [NETFLIX_TITLES.TYPE] is not a valid group by expression.

How should I redo this query?

Answer (score 2):

You only need `HAVING` for `COUNT(TYPE)`. Use `WHERE` to filter for type = 'TV Show' instead:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(COUNTRY,',',1), COUNT (*)
FROM NETFLIX_TITLES
WHERE TYPE = 'TV Show'
GROUP BY SPLIT_PART(COUNTRY,',',1)
HAVING COUNT(TYPE) >= 100
ORDER BY COUNT() DESC;
```